# Understanding how best to use Ansible for Updates/Upgrades of Tomcat based Applications

Tags: tomcat, ansible

Let me start off by saying apologies in advance if this question is posted in the wrong place and if what I am asking may seem like 'basic' knowledge, but I am completely new to Ansible and I am trying to understand how best to use it in our Org. I have completed a Ansible Basics course so I have a fundamental understanding of how Ansible works, what functionality it can perform and how plays work.

The eventual end goal is to move all of our Client Instances (DB and App Servers already hosted in Azure) into an AKS environment. As an Ops member, I was tasked with learning ansible as the end goal was to use it with AKS (Whether it be to setup new instances or just to facilitate Updates/Upgrades, this was not specified) After completing the course, I thought it would be an interesting task to use Ansible to perform our next App Upgrade using an Ansible Playbook and Host file with all of our App servers. The research I have done on top of the course I completed alluded to the fact that, besides using Ansible for the setup of new Servers, it could be used for CD or Rolling Upgrades.

The way a typical app server is currently setup in our environment will see a Tomcat instance being set up either, per client, or per application component. Either way, there are multiple tomcat instances per App server (Tomcat port 8080, 8181, etc). A normal update to a single app component will see the tomcat instance in question being stopped, the old war file being deleted as well as removing the old folders relating to the outdated app version, the new War file being copied over and renamed and, lastly, turning tomcat back on for that instance.

When multiple aspects of the application require updates, there is a powershell script that can be run to facilitate this. It will run all the necessary checks, stop the required tomcats, delete the files, copy and rename the war file, and make sure tomcat runs as normal thereafter.

In the current setup, is there a benefit to performing the updates with Ansible? Is there a way I can take the Powershell script and convert it into a Yaml format/Playbook and use Ansible to facilitate the Update instead? Would it be better to just run the Powershell script through Ansible (I fear this may just be a waste of time) or is it better to just continue using the Powershell script to perform these updates?

Sorry if these are 'dumb' or simple questions but I really feel lost at the moment. My colleague and I are the only ones with Ansible knowledge right now and we both only know the basics. We have been working on simple plays for now like mounting a disk, copying files over, etc. building on the process one step at a time. However, the more I think about it, the more intense this task seems (Identifying which War files are needed, deleting the necessary files, making sure the renaming of the War file is right per client instance, etc.)(I have been stumped just trying to figure out how to stop a particular tomcat instance and not just stop tomcat altogether).

I figured, before we continue, it would be best to get advice on whether this endeavor is worthwhile, is it better than continuing with the Powershell script we have been using for Upgrades. Any advice, recommendations, or even being pointed in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible is exactly meant for this kind of automations and configuration management. In my current organization we are heavily using ansible for such use cases.

Since you seem beginner in ansible it can be overwhelming at first. Once you get familiar with most of the ansible concepts and some standards that need to be followed while developing automations, you will find it much better than using any scripting language.

I would recommend you to start converting small automation or scripts into ansible at first. Once you get comfortable you can start targeting complex use cases. Before  moving to ansible please do a thorough research on availability of ansible modules for the devices, platforms, applications being used in your organization. if you find there are modules available in most cases it will be worth investing you time in long term.

Answering to your questing regarding using PowerShell scripts and ansible. I would not recommend to run PowerShell scripts through ansible as you wont be taking advantage of features provided by ansible. my recommendation would be to decode script find equivalent ansible modules for all the commands in the script and start writing a playbook. At the end you will find your ansible automation being more robust and reusable as compared to that script.

Hope this helps!